# How to split a string in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
  <h1>Lunch Checker</h1> 
      <div class="form-group" >
          <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
              placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
              class="form-control" ng-model="input">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="LunchCheckController()">
        Check If Too Much
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group message" id="result">
        <!-- Your message can go here. -->
        {{stack()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
(function() { 
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
           .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

    LunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function LunchCheckController ($scope) {
        $scope.input = ""; //Taking input from the user
        $scope.stack = function(input) {
            var array = input.split(',');
            if (array.length < 3) {
                return "Enjoy";
            } else {
                return "You gotta Stop boy!";
            } // Splitting the input
        };
    }
})();
```

I am kinda new to Angular.js. My aim is to get the string and split it. 
After splitting I want to satisfy a situation where "If the number of items are more than 3,print enjoy" otherwise "Anything else".

Comment: I reformatted your code to look visually correct, and it appears as though you either have a typo, or the function assigned to `$scope.stack` is incorrect. If you do have your `if`/`else` after a `return`, then it will never execute.

Comment: @krillgar Wait. Let me re-edit. Check now.

Comment: Plunker please.

Comment: your ng-click should be `stack(...)`

Comment: @K.Daniek Say what?

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you elaborate please?

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="LunchCheckController()">` looks wrong.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah Okay! Thanks for that. I changed it 'stack(input)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
  <h1>Lunch Checker</h1> 
      <div class="form-group" >
          <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
              placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
              class="form-control" ng-model="input">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="stack()">
        Check If Too Much
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group message" id="result">
        <!-- Your message can go here. -->
        {{message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
(function() { 
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
           .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

    LunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function LunchCheckController ($scope) {
        $scope.input = "";
        $scope.message = "";
        $scope.stack = function() {
            // already can access $scope.input
            // dont need to pass to stack()
            var array = $scope.input.split(',');

            // set $scope.message
            // instead of returning String
            if (array.length < 3) {
                $scope.message = "Enjoy";
            } else {
                $scope.message = "You gotta Stop boy!";
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Think about how the data flows:

- bind textbox to input
- click button run function
- check number of words
- set message

**Learning Angular.js**

First place to start is the Angular tutorials on their website.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

I didn't find them that useful at first, but they are the best place to start.

This video is a must if your new to angular, from 0 to hero in a few hours:

**Introduction to Angular.js in 50 Examples**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo

Then I advise watching a few youtube videos by **Misko Hevery**, he invented angular at google, and explains it very well.

This playlist is a good place to start.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4qVkWh1EAo&list=PL53194065BA276ACA

He explains the best features and also where people get stuck often.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `input` variable into stack function in the view like this `{{stack(input)}}`

Or use `var array = $scope.input.split(',');` instead of `var array = input.split(',');`

Comment: Thanks for that!
But I need the result on clicking the button and I am getting it without clicking it.

Comment: You can update some variable after button click. And use this variable in the view.

Comment: Thanks Man! It really helped me to understand a basic fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

This is the basic javascript split function.

With angular, you need to make an input box an `ng-model`, lets say str1.

All you need to do is

```
var res = $scope.str1.split(" ");
```

now its simple.. check for `res.length` and you get your things done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the JS

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
    .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

  LunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function LunchCheckController($scope) {
    $scope.input = "";
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.stack = function () {
      // already can access $scope.input
      // dont need to pass to stack()
      var array = $scope.input.split(',');

      // set $scope.message
      // instead of returning String
      if (array.length < 3) {
        $scope.message = "Enjoy";
      } else {
        $scope.message = "You gotta Stop boy!";
      }
    };
  }
})();
```